# JavaScript, simple state manager but object method calls gives "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to create a small game library with a state manager. The idea is to have a `_currentstate` and depending on which state is "activate" it will do different things. So I imagine the structure of the program should be something like this:

```
GameLib.Game
|
+-- States[]
    |
    +-- testgame.State1 <- has .init() method
    |
    +-- testgame.State2 <- has different .init() method
    | etc.
```

So I've created a new `GameLib` which has a StateManager, and two separate states with different `.init()` function.

```
// ----- test state 1 -----
testgame.State1 = {};
testgame.State1.prototype = {
    init: function(){
        console.log("State1 init(), do thing one");
    },

    update: function() {
        console.log("State1 update() for state one");
    },
    //etc.
}

    // initialize the gamelib framework
    var game = new GameLib.Game("test");

    // add game states test
    game.state.add("state1", testgame.State1);
    game.state.add("state2", testgame.State2);
    // etc.
```

And I've created a simple state manager, it will `add` all the states.

```
// ----- super simple state manager -----
GameLib.StateManager = function (gamelib) {
    this.gamelib = gamelib;
    this._currentState;
    this.states = {}; // hold all states
};

GameLib.StateManager.prototype = {

   add: function (key, state) {
        this.states[key] = state;
        this._currentState = key;
        return state;
    },
```

So far, this all seem works. However, when I try to call the .init() function like this:

```
this.states["state1"].init();
```

I get this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.states.state1.init is not a function

Even though the `this.states` is an object with two keys; `state1` and `state2`. And it looks like the `init` function is available.

[image]

Kind of a long post, but **my question is**:
Should the testgame.State1 be add in a different way? If so, how?
Or maybe the constructor is incorrect, how should I change it?

See code here
https://jsfiddle.net/qyw2oajc/3/

Comment: Note that it's available on the `prototype`, not on the `state1` itself. You need to do something like `state1 = new State1()`.

Comment: oops yeah, I've changed the `testgame.State` to a function and when adding it I do a `new state()` then it works :) thanks see updated code here https://jsfiddle.net/qyw2oajc/8/